# How to create NetworkCredentials for AuthType.Kerberos LdapConnection?

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, kerberos

In the case of `AuthType.Basic` this works in my server component:

```cs
// Provided by client
string username = "ou=user,uid=bob";
string password = "secr3t";

// Server side code that authenticates client at an LDAP server
string ldapServer = "my.server.org";
var credential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
var connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(ldapServer),
                                    credential,
                                    AuthType.Basic);
connection.Bind();
```

My next task is to use `AuthType.Kerberos` instead. As far I understood, the client sends a Kerberos ticket instead of its username and password to the server.
I imagine the result to look something like this:

```cs
// Provided by client
var kerberosTicket = /*???*/;

// Server side code that authenticates client at an LDAP server
string ldapServer = "my.server.org";
var credential = new NetworkCredential(/*kerberosTicket ???*/);
var connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(ldapServer),
                                    credential,
                                    AuthType.Kerberos);
connection.Bind();
```

What data type contains a Kerberos ticket and how can I convert it into a `NetworkCredential`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321290/kerberos-authentication-over-ldap

Comment: @Fabske Thanks for the hint. I believe that my scenario is a bit different though: In the linked question the application runs in the context of the user, that shall be authenticated. In my scenario the server runs in its own context and it needs to work with a Kerberos ticket instead of a username+password combination.

Comment: I'm not an expert (!!) but I don't think it can be used like you want . You still need to use username/password, and behind the scene it'll use Kerberos protocol to authenticate. That means send the user/pw to the authentication server, receive the ticket, and then use the ticket to access your target ressource. Here the target ressource is your authentication server, so there is no difference except (but it's a big point) that kerberos is encrypted. Kerberos ticket are binary and expire, so I don't think you'll be able to use like that. But once again I'm far from a Kerberos expert.

Comment: Also, Kerberos require access to the authentication server. That means you cannot use Kerberos via internet, because the domain controller is almost always behind firewall (and should be). In this case you need to use SSL.